# Lost client side javascript validation

Tags: javascript

I seems to have lost my client side validation and I'm not sure why.  I'm loading these and the server side it working fine.  I'm using Ajax.BeginForm with the TextBoxFor in the form.  Is this ehough to tell what might be going on?

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/scripts/jquery-1.4.4.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.blockUI.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jqury.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: I don't know what templating language you are using there, but it looks like you have a stray "<" before the "@Url" on the last script line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I lost it!

`<script src="<@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")"`

Notice the `"<"`. I found it!

Don't you have syntax highlighting that makes it obvouis?

Comment: any recommendation for syntax highlighters?

Comment: @robmorgan depens on the IDE. I presume your doing it in VS2010 so well, use that. Maybe find a better highlighter plugin or a validator.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be your quotations?
Try using single quotes around the src.

```
<script src='@Url.Content("~/scripts/jquery-1.4.4.min.js")' type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Do this for the rest.